# Data does not enter into mysql database through WordPress form using php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to create a form on WordPress page that allows me to enter data into a mysql table. when I enter the code the primary key auto increments however the data itself doesn't enter the database. Here is the table info in mysql:

```
    CREATE TABLE `macscabs`.`customers` (
`custno` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`sname` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`fname` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`homeaddr` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`commondest` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`mobileno` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`homeno` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`email` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `custno` ) 
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Below is the code from the WordPress page with the php on the same page:

```
<table>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] ?>">
<strong>Please enter your information in order to download the Macs Cabs App</strong>
<tr><td>
Surmane Name:</td><td><input name="sname" type="text" id="sname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
First Name:</td><td><input name="fname" type="text" id="fname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
Home Address:</td><td><input name="homeaddr" type="text" id="homeaddr"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
Most common Destination:</td><td><input name="commondest" type="text" id="commondest"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
Mobile Number:</td><td><input name="mobileno" type="text" id="mobileno"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
Home Number:</td><td><input name="homeno" type="text" id="homeno"></td></tr>
<td>
Email Address:</td><td><input name="email" type="text" id="email"></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</form></table>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("macscabs", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO `customers` (`sname`, `fname`, `homeaddr`, `commondest`, `mobileno`,       `homeno`, `email`)  
VALUES    ('{$_POST['sname']}','{$_POST['fname']}','{$_POST['homeaddr']}','{$_POST['commondest']}','{$_POST['m    obileno']}',
'{$_POST['homeno']}','{$_POST['email']}')";


 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 echo "1 record added";

$info = mysql_info(); echo $info;

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I have also tested the connection between the database and the web page by inserting the data manually without the use of the form by entering the code below and it works. However, when I try to insert it using the form I cant get it to work.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO customers (sname, fname, homeaddr, commondest, mobileno, homeno, email)
VALUES ('mcguinness','dave','moate','athlone','0254','56587',5)");
```

Comment: Are you missing a `<form>` element?

Comment: You can leave the form action blank (`<form action = "">`) and it will default to the current page, no need to fill it with PHP

Comment: Alfo, this has corrected the problem, thanks ever so much.

Comment: And... Please don't actually write your query like this. Use mysqli functions to start with.  Also, validate the data and clean it, making it safe, before pushing it into the database using mysqli_real_escape_string() as a bare minimum.  This is wide open for abuse, so please don't actually do this as you've written it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `customers` (`sname`, `fname`, `homeaddr`, `commondest`, `mobileno`, `homeno`, `email`)  
VALUES ('".$_POST['sname']."', '".$_POST['fname']."', '".$_POST['homeaddr']."', '".$_POST['commondest']."', '".$_POST['mobileno']."', '".$_POST['homeno']."', '".$_POST['email']."')";
```

Comment: no, it doesnt work, a row is added but there is no data entered

Comment: it is because of the action in the form. it should  be blank. `action""`

Answer (score 0):

VALUES (" '.$_post['EACH_NAME'].' ", " '.$_post['Next_Name_etc'].' ");

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Answer (score 0):

Of course it would be added into the mysql table with no data entered because you dont have a condition which indicate that the submit button is clicked so this means that once the page is loaded the insert query is also being executed. Why dont you try this

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){ // if the submit button is clicked

 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 if (!$con)
 {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 mysql_select_db("macscabs", $con);

  //using @musicvicious insert query
  $sql="INSERT INTO `customers` (`sname`, `fname`, `homeaddr`, `commondest`, `mobileno`, `homeno`, `email`)  VALUES ('".$_POST['sname']."', '".$_POST['fname']."', '".$_POST['homeaddr']."', '".$_POST['commondest']."', '".$_POST['mobileno']."', '".$_POST['homeno']."', '".$_POST['email']."')";


  if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  echo "1 record added";

  $info = mysql_info(); echo $info;

  mysql_close($con);

  }//end condition bracket
 ?>
```

But the best way is using $wpdb->query(); Check this [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 0):

```
this will do
<?php
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
        global $wpdb;
            $table = wp_achord;
            $data = array(
                'name' => $_POST['yourname'],
                'chord'    => $_POST['chord']
            );
            $format = array(
                '%s',
                '%s'
            );
            $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
            if($success){
            echo 'data has been save' ; 
}
}
else   {
?>
        <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="yourname">
        <textarea name="chord"></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>

       <?php }  ?>
```